Method 'DisposeAsync' in type 'Npgsql.NpgsqlBinaryExporter' from assembly 'Npgsql, Version=4.1.14.0
I'm encountering an issue when using the Npgsql library in my .NET Framework 4.6.1 project. Specifically, I'm getting the following exception when attempting to open an NpgsqlConnection:
Method 'DisposeAsync' in type 'Npgsql.NpgsqlBinaryExporter' from assembly 'Npgsql, Version=4.1.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7' does not have an implementation.

Code Reference:
The error occurs at the point where I open the connection:
public static DataTable FetchMasterData()
{
    NpgsqlConnection npgsqlConn = new NpgsqlConnection(Connection.ConnectionStringPostgreSQL);

    DataTable classMasterTbl = new DataTable();
    string sqlQuery = string.Empty;
    NpgsqlCommand npgsqlCommand = null;

    try
    {
        sqlQuery = @"SELECT * FROM ClassMaster";
        npgsqlCommand = new NpgsqlCommand(sqlQuery, npgsqlConn);

        npgsqlConn.Open(); // Getting Error here

        NpgsqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(npgsqlCommand);
        dataAdapter.Fill(classMasterTbl);

        return classMasterTbl;
    }
    catch (Exception dalExce)
    {
        // Handled LoaderExceptions
    }
    finally
    {
        npgsqlCommand?.Dispose();
        npgsqlConn.Close();
    }
}

.csProj
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>8.0.30703</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{DD58513D-7209-4DEF-A9EA-9C751367A14E}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>DAL</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>DAL</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <StartupObject />
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  </PropertyGroup>  
  <ItemGroup>
      <Reference Include="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
          <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.1.1.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll</HintPath>
      </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Npgsql, Version=4.1.14.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Npgsql.4.1.14\lib\net461\Npgsql.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Buffers, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Buffers.4.5.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Buffers.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.configuration" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Memory.4.5.3\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Memory.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Numerics" />
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.4.6.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Numerics.Vectors.4.4.0\lib\net46\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Text.Encodings.Web, Version=4.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Text.Encodings.Web.4.6.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Text.Encodings.Web.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Text.Json, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Text.Json.4.6.0\lib\net461\System.Text.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.4.5.4\lib\net461\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.ValueTuple, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.ValueTuple.4.5.0\lib\net461\System.ValueTuple.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="app.config" />
    <None Include="packages.config" />
    <None Include="Properties\Settings.settings">
      <Generator>SettingsSingleFileGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Settings.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Service Include="{3259AA49-8AA1-44D3-9025-A0B520596A8C}" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>  -->    
</Project>

Target Framework: .NET Framework 4.6.1
Npgsql Version: 4.1.14.0
Database: PostgreSQL
Research:
From what I've gathered, the DisposeAsync method is part of the asynchronous disposal pattern introduced in .NET Core 3.0. However, since I’m using .NET Framework 4.6.1, this method is not natively supported. This seems to be causing the runtime exception.
Questions:

Is there a version of Npgsql that is fully compatible with .NET Framework 4.6.1 and does not require methods like DisposeAsync?
If not, what would be the recommended approach to resolve this issue while still targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1? Would upgrading the .NET Framework be the only viable option?

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

I would try decreasing package version and see if it still fails, here you can find versions

Npgsql 4.1.14 targets the net461 TFM directly (see package page), so that TFM assembly should be picked up, not netcoreapp3.0. Double-check exactly what you're targeting and how you're including Npgsql, and post your full csproj if the problem persists.

@ShayRojansky - Please have a look at csproj, I have added.

@MichałTurczyn decreasing to 4.1.13?

@MichałTurczyn I downgraded to 4.0.17.0 and seems it it working now.
@ShayRojansky The question remains the same on why it is not working with the latest stable version of 4.x?

If it resolved your issue, does it answer your question? As of why IT is not working, i guess you have the answers already. If that is not sufficient, you can try analyzing source code, seems like it is open-source

I don't see anything immediately wrong there, I'd need to see a minimal project to investigate further (so a fully runnable hello world console program including the csproj which shows the problem)

After downgrading Npgsql to 4.0.17.0, I was able to resolve this issue.
